# Input/output error when mounting an NTFS partition

Tags: mount, ntfs

When I try to mount my laptop's hard drive from a live CD, this error message appears:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ubuntu/ACER: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/ubuntu/ACER"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

What should I do?

Comment: How about doing what the instruction tells you?

Comment: I can't boot on windows.

Comment: Looks like your disk is busted and likely it has nothing to do with Linux. Sorry :-(

Comment: so i can't recover my files?

Comment: No idea. If you use Windows, turn to Microsoft, NTFS is a Microsoft system. I would not try to repair it from Linux. Surely, there is some way of checking / repairing NTFS?